# hcidump binary not found

Tags: linux, bluez, buildroot, hci

I'm setting up the BlueZ protocol stack on a custom system using linux 3.3. I'm using buildroot to setup the filesystem, and specifically am using BlueZ-4.101.

I'm attempting to use the `hcidump` utility to get some logs, but the binary has not been installed.

I've checked that:

- Device driver is installed in kernel
- BlueZ Utils is enabled in buildroot .config file
- Other utilities work, such as `hcitool` or `hciconfig`

Going into the `Makefile` in `output/build/bluez_utils-4.101` it would appear that the object file `hcidump.o` is being compiled into a binary called `btmon`.

Further investigation would reveal that in `Makefile`, `btmon`is assigned to `am__EXEEXT_10`, and that is then assigned to the variable `noinst_PROGRAMS`.

So this is where I'm at. I'm pretty sure that this is an automatically generated `Makefile` by buildroot. I'm not sure how these files are generated, thus I'm unsure as to why `btmon` is being assigned to the `noinst_PROGRAMS` variable.

In summary, I believe that my version of BlueZ uses a binary `btmon` instead of `hcidump`. `btmon` is compiled (binary seen at `output/build/bluez_utils-4.101/monitor/btmon`), but not being installed onto my target system because of instructions in `Makefile`.

My best guess would something weird about compatibility between my kernel version and bluez. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In BlueZ 4, hcidump was distributed as a separate package, `bluez-hcidump`. This has never been packaged in buildroot, however. So either create your own package for `bluez-hcidump`, or switch to BlueZ 5. BleuZ 5 is provided by buildroot starting from 2014.08.